# Javascript: weird syntax error when using "label"

Tags: javascript, loops, label, undefined

This code piece

```
abc:
var i=0;
for (; i < 10; ++i)
    if (i == 8) break abc;
```

has runtime exception, saying

```
SyntaxError: Undefined label 'abc'
```

If I remove the line of

```
var i=0;
```

Then it's OK.

This is weird to me. 
Does javascript requires any label, if used by "break"/"continue", definition is only available to the code block right following it, or else it's not accessible?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the label needs to be on the line above the loop. Try putting the `var i = 0;` above the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

> The break statement needs to be nested within the referenced label.

So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your label needs to be directly before the loop:

```
var i=0;
abc:
for (; i < 10; ++i)
    if (i == 8) break abc;
```